# SQL String aggregation returns different results based on location of variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

My code:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null drop table #t1

create table #t1 (ID int, name varchar(10))

insert into #t1 values (1,'2'), (6,'2'), (6,'2'), (1,'4')

DECLARE @CHARS VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT @CHARS = @CHARS + name + ', ' -- <---CODE OF INTEREST
FROM #t1
```

This returns `2, 2, 2, 4,`. All is well.

However, When I change the above code to append the comma and space first :

```
DECLARE @CHARS VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT @CHARS = ', ' + @CHARS + name -- <---CODE OF INTEREST
FROM #t1

SELECT @CHARS
```

it returns `, , , , 2224`. Shouldn't it return `, 2, 2, 2, 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the second formula is: for every record it appends the string to the right side of @CHARS

Assume you have

```
insert into #t1 values (1,'2'), (6,'3'), (6,'4'), (1,'5')
```

to make it more clear

For the first row it returns `", 2"`

for the second row, you @CHARS will be `", "` + `", 2"` + "3"

for the third row, @CHARS is `", , 23"` so will set @CHARS to  `", "` + `", , 23"` + `"4"`

try below queries to see what's going on:

```
DECLARE @CHARS VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT top 1 @CHARS = ', ' + @CHARS + name -- <---CODE OF INTEREST
FROM #t1

print @CHARS
go

Result: , 2
--------------------------
DECLARE @CHARS VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT top 2 @CHARS = ', ' + @CHARS + name -- <---CODE OF INTEREST
FROM #t1

print @CHARS
go

Result: , , 23
----------------------
DECLARE @CHARS VARCHAR(100) = ''
SELECT top 3 @CHARS = ', ' + @CHARS + name -- <---CODE OF INTEREST
FROM #t1

print @CHARS
go
Result: , , , 234
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! This makes a bunch of sense! Can't believe I didn't hash that out myself >:/ Thank you!